# How to test if a lambda expression's query result is null?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
var query = from emp in dbEmp.Employees
            join dept in dbEmp.Departments on emp.DeptID equals dept.DeptID
            where dept.DepartmentName.Contains(this.TextBox1.Text)
            select new
            {
                EmpID = emp.EmpID,
                EmpName = emp.EmpName,
                Age = emp.Age,
                Address = emp.Address,
                DeptName = dept.DepartmentName
            };

if (query == null)
    Label1.Text = "no results match your search";

GridView1.DataSource = query;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Everything works in the right way, but the label doesn't show the message when query result returns null. The label can show without condition (query==null). So how to test if a var query result returns nothing? Thanks

Comment: LINQ query expressions cannot actually return null, only empty sets.

Comment: @BoltClock, what if you put a `.FirstOrDefault()` on the end? Does that not count?

Comment: @jb: Once you put something like `FirstOrDefault` on the end, you have "left the monad" and are no longer dealing with a LINQ query expression. A query expression has a type like `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` while `FirstOrDefault` has a type like `T`.

Answer (score 9):

If I could teach people just one thing about LINQ it is this:

**The value of a query expression is *the query* not the *results* of the query.**

When you say

```
var q = from c in customers where c.City == "London" select c.Name;
```

q does not contain a sequence of customer names from London. q contains *a query* representing the operation *query the customers database as follows...*.  The query does not run; all you've done is created the query. When you *enumerate* the query, that's when the query fetches the results.

Answer (score 8):

```
if (!query.Any())
{
 // no results
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The condition you're looking for is

```
if (query.Count() == 0)
```

Since the actual `query` variable will always contain the valid (non-null) query object itself, not the query results.

Comment: `Count()` enumerates whole query. `FirstOrDefault()` enumerates only the first element.

Comment: `Any()` is better than either of them, as it doesn't give a false-empty when the sequence contains a null element, it doesn't enumerate the whole sequence, and it says *exactly* what you're trying to do: see if there are any elements.

Comment: @Jon: I would expect `.Count()` to send a `SELECT COUNT(...)` query, not enumerate the whole sequence. It's bad, but not as bad.

Comment: @Gabe: For LINQ to SQL or something similar, I agree. For LINQ to Objects, it will enumerate everything (if it's not an `ICollection`). There's still the readability benefit, IMO.

Comment: I actually agree with Jon here, because the underlying query provider should not (in theory) impact the way we write the LINQ query.

Answer (score 2):

The query is never null. The result of the query may be an empty set. You can either check if the query contains at least one item or you can force it to execute completely.

```
if (!query.Any()) {
    // no results
}

GridView1.DataSource = query;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

or

```
var results = query.ToList();
if (!results.Any()) {
    // no results
}

// Here you should use results instead of query because
// there is no need to re-evaluate the query again.

GridView1.DataSource = results;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

In this case the latter solution is most likely better.

Comment: Your second option is fine, but your first is a problem: What if the first result was just null?

Comment: I don't see the problem. The `query` cannot be null and `query.FirstOrDefault()` is expected to be either null or a instance.

Comment: @Gabe: Your point is a good one in general (although I would prefer to see `Any()` instead of `Count()==0`) but when the query uses `new { ... }` as in this case, we know that there will never be any null elements. That can change whether or not `FirstOrDefault` is appropriate.

Comment: It would work for this *particular* query, but not all queries. Your answer implies that `query.FirstOrDefault()` will always tell you if a query returns at least one result, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Jon: `query.Count()` is horrible, but `results.Count` (the property, not the extension method) is fine. The problem with the answer is that doesn't say that it only works for queries whose projection is always a constructor.

Comment: @Gabe: That's true, I'd missed that. I'd still prefer using `Any()` as it expresses in one token what you're trying to achieve - you're not really interested in a comparison between the count and 0; you're interested in whether there are *any* elements.

Comment: @Gabe & Jon: I decided to do the right thing and I substituted `FirstOrDefault()` with `Any()`. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid evaluating the query twice, so first you should save its results. Then check it for emptiness and either databind or show an error:

```
var results = query.ToList();
if (!results.Any())
    Label1.Text = "no results match your search";

GridView1.DataSource = results;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: @abatishchev: `ToList` saves the results of the query to avoid evaluating the query twice (`ToArray` would work just as well). The `DataBind` call is going to fully evaluate the query anyway, so we may as well save the results of it to use with the `Any` call. Does this make sense now?